# Unable to display title of video element in the UI

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning webapplication development using HTML,CSS and JS. Curretly i am trying to display all the videos stored to the UI, i am stuck in displaying the names of the video below them. Currently i am able to display the title of video element only for one video, but if i add more videos i am not able to dispaly the title below them,  below is the code i am working on, Can you guys please guide me to achieve to display the title in video element on all the videos

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
  <title>Videos</title>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="videos.css">  
  </head>

<body>
   <header>  
  <h1> Main logo </h1>
  <nav>
   <ul id="nav"> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 </header>
 <div class="divider"></div>


<figure>
  <video id="video_player" title="movie1" width="300" height="240" controls>
    <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <figcaption id="meta"></figcaption>
 </figure>

<figure>
<video id="video_player1" title="movie2" controls width="300" height="240" controls> 
<source src="2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video> 
  <figcaption id="meta1"></figcaption>
</figure> 

<figure>
<video id="video_player3" title="movie3" controls width="300" height="240" controls> 
<source src="3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video> 
  <figcaption id="meta2"></figcaption>
</figure> 


    <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="videos.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
header {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 0px 6px 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

header h1 {
 font-size: 30px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 50px;
}

nav ul{

 padding: 0px;
float: left;
}

nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type:none;
 color: white;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

nav ul li a{
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}


.divider{
 background-color: red;
 height: 5px;

}


figure {
    display: inline-block;    
}
figure video {
    vertical-align: top;
}
figure figcaption {    
    text-align: center;
}
```

js code:

```
    var myVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('video_player' , 'video_player1' , 'video_player2'),    
    title = myVideoPlayer.getAttribute("title"),    
    meta = document.getElementById('meta' , 'meta1' , 'meta2');

myVideoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
    meta.innerHTML =  title ;
});
```

edit:

```
var meta = document.getElementById("meta");
var metaa = nums.getElementsByTagName("figcaption");

var newNums = [];

for (var i=0; i < metaa.length; i++) {
    newNums.push( parseInt( metaa[i].innerHTML, 10 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From where are you calling the eventlistener ('loadedmetadata') ?

Adding something like this code makes it work.

```
function loadedmetadata(){ meta.innerHTML = title ; } loadedmetadata();
```

Check your function loadedmetadata, I think it's not getting called.

Also this is wrong.

```
meta = document.getElementById('meta' , 'meta1' , 'meta2');
```

This will only take the first value.
You need to create a function which will loop through the id list.

Comment: function loadedmetadata(){ meta.innerHTML = title ; } loadedmetadata();